# Why does Python return a Rect style object error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, ipython

```
import time,random
import pygame
global swidth,sheight,screen,background

pygame.init()
inf=pygame.display.Info()
swidth=int(inf.current_w)
sheight=int(inf.current_h)

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((swidth,sheight),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
background=pygame.color.Color(0,0,0,255)
screen.fill(background)

def puttext(surf,pos,text,font,size,color,flag):
    fontrend=pygame.font.Font(font,size)
    textrend=fontrend.render(text,1,color)
    if flag=="center":
        textpos=textrend.get_rect()
        textpos.center=surf.get_rect().center
    elif flag == "left":
        textpos=(surf.get_rect().left+2,surf.get_rect().top)
    elif flag=="right":
        textpos=(surf.get_rect().right-textrend.get_rect().width-2,surf.get_rect().top)
    else:
        textpos=pos
    surf.blit(textrend,textpos)

class paddle():
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,velx,vely,width,height,color):
        self.posx=posx
        self.posy=posy
        self.velx=velx
        self.vely=vely
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.color=color
        self.ltime=time.time()
    def move(self):
        global swidth,sheight,screen,background
        ttime=self.ltime
        self.ltime=time.time()
        diff=self.ltime-ttime
        #Handle collisions
        newx=self.posx+self.velx*(diff)
        newy=self.posy+self.vely*(diff)
        #check for paddle collisions
        if newy<0:  #hit ceiling
            self.posy=0
        elif newy+self.height>sheight:
            self.posy=sheight-self.height
        else:
            self.posy=newy
            self.posx=newx
    def setvelx(self,vel):
        self.velx=vel
    def setvely(self,vel):
        self.vely=vel
    def getvelx(self):
        return self.velx
    def getvely(self):
        return self.vely
    def erase(self,surf):
        global swidth,sheight,screen,background
        pygame.draw.rect(surf,background,pygame.rect.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
    def draw(self,surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf,self.color,pygame.rect.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)

class arrow():
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,velx,vely,color,height,width,thisgame):
        self.posx=posx
        self.posy=posy
        self.velx=velx
        self.vely=vely
        self.color=color
        self.height=height
        self.width=width
        self.ltime=time.time()
        self.text="It's Clobberin' Time!"
        self.game=thisgame # game object for this arrow
    def move(self):
        ttime=self.ltime
        self.ltime=time.time()
        diff=self.ltime-ttime
        #Handle collisions
        newx=self.posx+self.velx*(diff)
        newy=self.posy+self.vely*(diff)
        #check for collisions
        #handle collisions
        #if newy>=sheight: #past the edge
            #newy=2*(sheight)-newy
            #self.vely=self.vely*(-1)
        #elif newy<0:
            #newy=-1*newy
            #self.vely=self.vely*(-1)
        if newx+self.width>=self.game.player2.paddle.posx: #possibly hit right paddle
            padx=self.game.player2.paddle.posx
            padtop=self.game.player2.paddle.posy
            padbot=self.game.player2.paddle.posy+self.game.player2.paddle.height
            padvelx=self.game.player2.paddle.velx
            padvely=self.game.player2.paddle.vely
            dt=(padx-self.posx-self.height)/(self.velx+.00001)
            padtop=padtop+padvely*dt
            padbot=padbot+padvely*dt
            newy=self.posy+self.vely*dt
            if newy>=padtop and newy<=padbot:
                #newx=2*(padx)-newx
                #self.velx=self.velx*10
                #self.vely=self.vely+self.game.player2.paddle.vely/2
                self.game.player1.score=self.game.player1.score+1
        if newx+self.width<=self.game.player1.paddle.posx+self.game.player1.paddle.width: #possibly hit left paddle
            padx=self.game.player1.paddle.posx+self.game.player1.paddle.width
            padtop=self.game.player1.paddle.posy
            padbot=self.game.player1.paddle.posy+self.game.player1.paddle.height
            padvelx=self.game.player1.paddle.velx
            padvely=self.game.player1.paddle.vely
            dt=(-padx+self.posx)/(self.velx+.00001)
            padtop=padtop+padvely*dt
            padbot=padbot+padvely*dt
            newarrowy=self.posy+self.vely*dt
            if newy>=padtop and newy<=padbot:
                #newx=2*(padx)-newx
                self.velx=self.velx*10
                self.vely=self.vely+self.game.player1.paddle.vely/2
                self.game.player2.score=self.game.player2.score+1
        if newx>=swidth: #past the edge
            self.velx=self.velx*10
        elif newx<=0:
            self.velx=self.velx*10
            self.posx=newx
            self.posy=newy
    def setvelx(self,vel):
        self.velx=vel
    def setvely(self,vel):
        self.vely=vel
    def getvelx(self):
        return self.velx
    def getvely(self):
        return self.vely
    def erase(self,surf):
        global swidth,sheight,background
        #pygame.draw.rect(surf,background,pygame.Rect(self.posx-9,self.posy-39,200,50),0)
        pygame.draw.rect(surf,background,pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
    def draw(self,surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf,self.color,pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
        #puttext(screen,(self.posx-9,self.posy-39),self.text,None,30,(255,255,255,255),None)

class player():
    def __init__(self,name,number):
        global swidth,sheight,screen,background
        self.name=name
        self.number=number
        self.score=0
        if number==1:
            self.paddle=paddle(5,random.randint(0,sheight-50),0,0,5,50,(255,0,0,255))
        if number==2:
            self.paddle=paddle(swidth-10,random.randint(0,sheight-50),0,0,5,50,(0,255,0,255))
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

class scoreboard():
    def __init__(self,width,height,color,game):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.color=color
        self.game=game
        self.board=pygame.surface.Surface((self.width,self.height))
        self.board=self.board.convert_alpha()
        self.fps=0
    def ptext(self,x,y,text,surf,color):
        puttext(surf,(x,y),text,None,20,color,"None")
    def draw(self):
        self.board.fill(self.color)
        self.ptext(5,5,"Player 1:   "+str(self.game.player1.get_score()),self.board,(220,220,100,150))
        self.ptext(5,20,"Player 2:   "+str(self.game.player2.get_score()),self.board,(220,220,100,150))
        self.ptext(5,35,"FPS:   "+str(self.fps),self.board,(220,220,100,150))
        screen.blit(self.board,(int(swidth/2)-int(self.width/2),0))
    def erase(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0,0),pygame.rect.Rect(int(swidth/2)-int(self.width/2),0,self.width,self.height),0)

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.arrows=[]
        self.player1=player("bob",1)
        self.player2=player("fred",2)
        self.score=scoreboard(150,60,(0,0,255,50),self)
        self.gameloop()
    def gameloop(self):
        global swidth,sheight,screen,background
        t1=time.time()
        cnt=0
        ttot=0
        paddlespeed=300
        puttext(screen,(0,0),"IT'S CLOBBERIN' TIME!",None,50,(255,255,255,255),"center")
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill(background)
        time.sleep(2)
        while True:
            pygame.event.pump()
            keysup=pygame.event.get(pygame.KEYUP)
            keysdown=pygame.event.get(pygame.KEYDOWN)
            pygame.event.get()
            if len(keysup)>0:
                for a in keysup:
                    if a.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        exit()
                    if a.key==pygame.K_UP:
                        self.player2.paddle.vely=self.player2.paddle.vely+paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.player2.paddle.vely=self.player2.paddle.vely-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_a:
                        self.player1.paddle.vely=self.player1.paddle.vely+paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_z:
                        self.player1.paddle.vely=self.player1.paddle.vely-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.player2.paddle.velx=self.player2.paddle.velx-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.player2.paddle.velx=self.player2.paddle.velx+paddlespeed
                    #if a.key==pygame.K_q:
                        #self.arrows.append(arrow(self.player1.paddle.width,self.player1.paddle.posy+.5*self.player1.paddle.height,150,0,pygame.color.Color(255,255,28,255),0,75,self))
                    #if a.key==pygame.K_p:
                        #self.arrows.append(arrow(self.player2.paddle.posx,self.player2.paddle.posy+.5*self.player2.paddle.height,-150,0,pygame.color.Color(255,255,28,255),0,75,self))
            if len(keysdown)>0:
                for a in keysdown:
                    if a.key==pygame.K_UP:
                        self.player2.paddle.vely=self.player2.paddle.vely-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.player2.paddle.vely=self.player2.paddle.vely+paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_a:
                        self.player1.paddle.vely=self.player1.paddle.vely-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_z:
                        self.player1.paddle.vely=self.player1.paddle.vely+paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.player2.paddle.velx=self.player2.paddle.velx+paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.player2.paddle.velx=self.player2.paddle.velx-paddlespeed
                    if a.key==pygame.K_q:
                        self.arrows.append(arrow(self.player1.paddle.width+5,self.player1.paddle.posy+.5*self.player1.paddle.height,200,0,pygame.color.Color(255,255,28,255),0,75,self))
                    if a.key==pygame.K_p:
                        self.arrows.append(arrow(self.player2.paddle.posx-75,self.player2.paddle.posy+.5*self.player2.paddle.height,-200,0,pygame.color.Color(255,255,28,255),0,75,self))


#           time.sleep(.1)
            self.score.erase()
            self.player1.paddle.erase(screen)
            self.player2.paddle.erase(screen)
            for x in self.arrows:
                x.erase(screen)
                x.move()
            self.player1.paddle.move()
            self.player2.paddle.move()

            ttot=time.time()-t1+ttot            
            if ttot>1:
                self.score.fps=cnt
                cnt=0
                ttot=0
            t1=time.time()
            cnt=cnt+1

            for x in self.arrows:
                x.draw(screen)
            self.player1.paddle.draw(screen)
            self.player2.paddle.draw(screen)
            self.score.draw()
            pygame.display.flip()


    game()


Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 270, in <module>
        game()
    line 186, in __init__
        self.gameloop()
    line 263, in gameloop
        x.draw(screen)
    line 144, in draw
        pygame.draw.rect(surf,self.color,pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
```

I don't understand why Python returns this error. Line 144 is correct if analyzed in context of the syntax. The argument seems to be syntaxilly correct. Is there any mistake in the structure of the code, maybe in the interaction between line 144 and other lines?

Comment: when does this happen?

Comment: The python window disappears when the arrow passes the left-right edge of the screen, which is not supposed to happen, and then Command Prompt returns the above error.

Comment: what arrow might that be?

Answer (score 1):

```
pygame.draw.rect(surf,self.color,pygame.Rect(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
```

This must be;

```
pygame.draw.rect(surf,self.color,(self.posx,self.posy,self.width,self.height),0)
```

You are trying to put a rectstyle object in rect coords. Valid syntax is;

```
a= where you want to draw your rect, it's a surface object,screen
b= RGB color of rect
c=coordinates in a tuple
pygame.draw.rect(a,b,c)
```

`c=coordinates in a tuple` actually means,

```
(x,y,wx,hy)
x= x coordinate of your rectangle
y= y corrdinate of your rectangle
wx= the lenght of x coord of your rectangle. If `x` is bigger,your rectangle is bigger.
hx= the height of y coord of your rectangle. If `y` is bigger, your rectangle is bigger.
```

Comment: I didn't see any improvement. Moreover I'm not understanding the reason of the error. What is the flaw in the structure?